Can you identify this curve generated by a rotating Reuleaux triangle?
The image below shows the locus of the centroid of a Reuleaux triangle as it rotates and revolves about a stationary one. The curve is shown as blue dots. I'm trying to determine if the curve has been seen or described previously. It's in the spirit of the epitrochoid, but clearly far removed. The animation is kind of sparse to meet the image size requirement. The curve is shown in its entirety in the figure below it.



What have you tried?

@jjagmath Thanks for your comment. It was not the solution for the locus as much as whether such a curve has been seen before. I have many books on curves but have not seen anything like this. As far as the solution goes, I have a pretty good approximate solution that is a cosine function riding on a circle. The solution agrees with numerical to within 5% everywhere.

Isn't this "simply" the union of three circular arcs (the "corners") and three epitrochoidal arcs (the "sides")?

The epitrochoid that contributes the non-circular pieces of your curve is also called a limaçon of Pascal. So what you have is a kind of Frankenstein’s monster of well-known curves.

I have found two curves similar to the locus the centroid described above. These are found at 2dcurves.com and a downloadable pdf.
The first of these is the Cassinian curve of the regular polygon type, (p. 109) with a polar equation
$$
r(\theta)=\sqrt[n]{\cos n\theta\pm \sqrt{a-\sin^2n\theta}}
$$
where $n=3$.
The second is the botanic curve (p. 273), with polar equation
$$
r(\theta)=1+a\sin n\theta
$$
where, again, $n=3$.
Of course, these equations must scaled and/or rotated to be brought into compliance with the computed locus.
Prior to finding these curves I developed an approximate equation for the locus upon observation that the absolute value of the locus is very nearly sinusoidal. This was expressed as
$$
r(\theta)=h\cos n\theta+R
$$
where $h$ is the amplitude of the sinusoid and $R$ its mean value (or radius of the guiding circle). Clearly, this must be a version of the botanic curve.
Unfortunately, while remarkably similar to the locus, neither of these curves is identical to it. A comparison is shown in the figure below. The parameters in the models were chosen to match the actual curve at its extrema.

